# How to update/upgrade the Facebook API version?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine

How do I upgrade/update my Graph API ver from 2.1 to 2.5?

- The latest Graph API version of Facebook is v2.5.
- App A uses Graph API v2.1. This app has some login error which does not allow my app to login with the FB credentials.
- Another app uses v2.4, and this allows the login without issue.

So, I was thinking of updating/upgrading my App A's graphAPI to v2.4 or 2.5. However, their official doc does not specifically state how to upgrade it but rather just the call method.

**Software**

- Unity ver: 4.6.9 f1
- Facebook Unity SDK 6.2.2
- iOS SDK 3.2.0

Answer (score 2):

If you upgrade to the latest iOS SDK, you will also (per default) use the latest version of the Graph API (at the moment when the SDK is released). The latest version in the [SDK 3.x branch](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/change-log-3.x) uses v2.2. I would advise to upgrade to the [SDK 4.x branch](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/change-log-4.x) to make use of the most recent features.

See also the [Platform Upgrade Guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading) for all changes and how to work around those.